# mongodb spring connection lost overnight

Tags: mongodb, azure, spring-data-jpa, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using azure cosmosdb with mongoAPI (spring data, mongoRepository)
Each morning, first request to fetch data from mongo causes exception:

Following requests succeed without doing any actions.

Any idea what might be causing this?
Is there a way to have spring automatically recover connections without failing request?

Thanks

The exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception sending message; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:107)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2135)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1978)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1784)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1767)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:641)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.execute(MongoQueryExecution.java:79)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryExecution$ResultProcessingExecution.execute(MongoQueryExecution.java:411)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:94)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
...
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
        at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:465)
        at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:208)
        at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendMessage(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:90)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendMessage(DefaultConnectionPool.java:429)
        at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.sendMessage(CommandProtocol.java:189)
        at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.execute(CommandProtocol.java:111)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:168)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:289)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:176)
        at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:216)
        at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:207)
        at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:113)
        at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:516)
        at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:510)
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:431)
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:404)
        at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:510)
        at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:81)
        at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:836)
        at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:823)
        at com.mongodb.DBCursor.initializeCursor(DBCursor.java:870)
        at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:142)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1964)
        ... 129 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
        at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
        at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:886)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:857)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:75)
        at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:204)
        ... 150 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Did you try setting keep-alive?

Comment: I'm connecting to mongo using spring boot properties file with properties spring.data.mongodb.*
Do you know how to configure keepalive?
Thanks

Comment: i don't think you can do this from properties file

Comment: same issue here

Answer (score 1):

It closes the connection because of passing the maximum connection idle time.

You will need to set this property according to your requirement.

```
maxConnectionIdleTime
```

This can be set either on your Mongo configuration or application profile.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can set keep-alive like that:

```
    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        MongoClientOptions.Builder optionsBuilder = MongoClientOptions.builder();
        optionsBuilder.socketKeepAlive(true);
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClientURI(mongoUri, optionsBuilder));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
For various reasons we moved to a stand-alone mongo outside azure and the problem didn't reproduce.

Comment: If you will decide to move back to Azure you can also try to set maxConnectionIndeTime option due to this Azure issue - http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#known-issues
It helped to me.

Comment: I had a similar issue when using an Azure Cosmos DB (Mongo). Setting the keep-alive didn't work, but setting the maxConnectionIdleTime time did resolve the issue.

Comment: @DillonRyanRedding I'm having the same issue but looking into the docs it looks like maxConnectionIdleTime is by default 0, which means not limit. What do you guys configure it as?

Comment: @dmendezg I set it as suggested by the docs provided by Vasyl Teraz. Specifically, http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#q-how-do-i-handle-dropped-connections-on-azure-classic. I did make it configurable through Spring's external configuration in case it needs change later.